# Different definition for sender

Tags: swift

So I used sender a lot in swift but it confuses what exactly it does.

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_sender: AnyObject){
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "newScreen", sender: code)
}
```

Someone explain the difference between the two senders pls. It kind of confuses me because it has the same name but different functions.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of an `IBAction` tells you who caused the action. In your case, when you push the button that triggered this `IBAction` to be invoked, `sender` will be set to that button.

The word `sender` is nothing more than a name. It's a typical convention.

In your case, it's better to use a more strongly typed argument, with a more descriptive name, such as:

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_ button: NSButton) { // or UIButton for iOS
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "newScreen", sender: code)
}
```

Comment: @DarrenZou That indicates that the entity that invoked the `btnPressed` `IBAction` (the button) is different from the entity that invoked `performSegue`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, Fixed. Although i don't think it's necessary to have an `_`, but having anything else will make this be considered a different method, and will sever the `IBAction` binding

Comment: the IBAction sender tells it who can trigger the button.. but the perform segue I can put a string in it or anything else and it will still perform the segue.. so what's the purpose of the sender for performSegue..

Comment: @DarrenZou It tells the `performSegue` method who invoked the `performSegue` method.

Comment: it still doesn't make sense because any arbitrary value can pass through the sender for performSegue and it will still run, what should be there if you were writing the code?

Comment: Yes, any arbitrary value can be put in, but that doesn't mean it doesn't make sense. When you divide by zero, you get a crash. That doesn't mean division doesn't make sense, it just means it's built around the assumption that you honor the implicit contract formed by its argument preconditions

Comment: @DarrenZou if this were my code, I would follow the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performseguewithidentifier): `sender

The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue.
`

Comment: If I'm calling this segue from VC1 to VC2, then I'll probably toss in the VC1 instance as the sender

Comment: so that sender doesn't necessarily invokes the segue because the button already does that; the sender for performSegue is only for information sending like strings, ints, arrays etc?

Comment: @DarrenZou The button doesn't invoke `performSegue`. The button invokes the `IBAction` of your `ViewController`. it's the `btnPressed` method that invokes `performSegue`. So it makes most sense to pass the current VC instance (`self`), whose `btnPressed` method invoked `performSegue`